# Slicing the word but cant make the output correct

Tags: python, slice

is it possible for the string `rotten tomatoes` to produce the output `oat` using slicing? ive been trying like using steps but i cant seem to get it right. ive tried:

```
my_string = 'rotten tomatoes'

print (my_string[8:13:2]
print (my_string[-3:-8:-2])
```

but they still produce the word `oao`

Comment: hmm, there's only a finite number of slices you could do, so you could brute force it.

Comment: You can see by eye it's not possible...

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explain what you are trying to do, and offer more context on the constraints. For example, s[-3:-4:-1] + s[-5:-3:1] still uses slicing but not 'just slicing' to get 'oat' (s="rotten tomatoes")

Comment: Why do you believe this problem is solvable with slicing?

Comment: You coud do this: `"".join(my_string[i] for i in [8,13,2])`

Answer (score 2):

No. The letters don't occur in steps. `'a'` is the crucial character, since it only appears once.

Going forwards, the sequence `'at'` can only be made with a step of 1, but `'o'` is 2 characters before.

Going backwards, the sequence `'oa'` can only be made with a step of 2, but `'t'` is 3 characters later.

Comment: how about print (my_string[8] + my_string[10] + my_string[11]) is that like logically correct?

Comment: Try it. Does it work?

Comment: @ayokona That's not slicing, it's indexing, plus addition. If you're allowed to do addition, then you can do `my_string[8:9] + my_string[10:12]`, but I don't know why you would unless this is for a puzzle or something